# Is there a Z order value, for clicks on Highcharts tooltips?

Tags: highcharts

I am noticing something strange; I have a click event on a chart, and the chart fire up the event no problem.

Then I add a link in the tooltip, but when I click on it; the chart event fire, not the one that should open the link.

It works only if the tooltip will render on an area that is not part of the plot area (say, a value is high enough to render a tooltip on the title bar; if I click on that link, it will work).

I suspect that there is some sort of parameter that tell highcharts if the link in the tooltip is above the chart plot area? Otherwise it is impossible to have the tooltip open a link, if the highcharts click event is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `useHTML` flag as true.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/voh6ebt8/

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/voh6ebt8/show

Comment: works like a charm: style color added in the <a> tag and everything is fabulous :)